# How to use the Repository Pattern to handle complex Reads(SELECTs)?

Tags: php, mysql, repository-pattern, laravel-5

I've seen a lot of the `$repo->findAll()` or `$repo->findById($id)`examples, but I'm looking for how to expand on this for more complex Reads.

For example, let's say I have a datagrid that represents a  SELECT query with several JOINs in it. I'm going to need to do these things:

- Sorting
- Filtering (`WHERE` conditions, some of which happen on the `JOIN` clauses of the query)
- Columns (I don't want to `SELECT *`, so I need to specify the fields I want)
- Limit (pagination)
- Count (I need to know the total number of rows from all pages. Perhaps I do this in a seperate repo method/query.)

I'm not sure I'm comfortable using an existing *query builder* package because I'm not sure how testable and database-agnostic it would be (in other words, it might be *too flexible*). I do know that I do NOT want to use an *ORM* for this project. I'm using the *Data Mapper + Repository* approach instead.

**How would I do this using the Repository Pattern?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sometimes, I believe the "Answer" to a question involves "lowering expectations".)

I believe you are asking too much for a "Repository Pattern".  There are many 3rd party software packages that attempt to isolate the user from MySQL.  They generally have limitations.  Often a limitation is in scaling -- they are not designed to work with huge datasets in complex ways.

Whenever I use the Repository Pattern, it seems that I am doing little more than encapsulating a one (or a few) SQL statement and putting the encapsulated method (subroutine) in a separate file.  Oh, I believe in doing it.  I just don't believe in magic.

Let me pick apart two of your 'requirements'.  They are good for encapsulating, but not necessarily good for the Repository Pattern.

Pagination using OFFSET and LIMIT...  For simple datasets, this works fine.  But I watched a project melt down after they did this.  They required the obvious parameters (offset and limit) and did the obvious thing (construct and execute `SELECT ... OFFSET $offs LIMIT $lim`).  Then they built a web page that had 126,000 "pages" worth of data.  Then something did Next, Next, Next, ... until the system melted down.

The problem was depending on offset and limit instead of "Next" and "Prev", and "remembering where you left off".  (I have a blog on that topic.)  Note that the "solution" cannot be performed in the encapsulated routine, but involves UI changes and user expectation changes, plus code.

The other one I want to comment on is SQL_COUNT_FOUND_ROWS...  So simple, so easy.  But so deadly.  As recently a as this week I was advising someone who's data had grown so much that he was having performance problems due to that counting technique.  Many of the possible solutions involve more than can be stuck in a Repository Pattern.  For example, the typical search engine long ago punted on getting the exact count and, instead, "managed the user expectations" by showing "10 items out of *about* 1,340,000".  That, doubtless, took a lot of code in a lot of places, not just a simple enhancement to one SQL statement.  It probably took multiple servers.

So, encapsulate - Yes.  Repository Pattern - only somewhat.  And become an expert in raw SQL.

Comment: Yeah Rick, I think you are right on track with what I was thinking. I just need to encapsulate (which will possibly reduce some of the total number of queries I have) and keep these queries all in one place (in several folders, but all under a single parent folder...instead of spread out throughout the app). The goal also it to ensure the queries return arrays/objects to the rest of the app so that the rest of the app remains database agnostic and I can test easily (mock the returned data from the query).

Comment: Also, thanks for the heads up on the pagination and COUNT. I have read these warnings in the past. I'll see if I can update jqGrid to just use "prev" "next" and "last" links. So far the things that have kept us alive is by keeping a watch on the need for RAM (as long as the "hot" data stays in RAM we are good) and also I've set my primary key to be composite keys that order the data in a way that we mostly filter for it (in other words, these primary keys help our queries to splice the data out in proper sized chunks, so that pagination/count/etc doesn't become an issue).

Comment: FYI, the fact that I don't trust ORMs too much should tell you I'm very comfortable with raw queries. :-)

Comment: Oh, and one more thing, you are right in that I can't expect the Repo Pattern to be a silver bullet here. I just need to do what I can to encapsulate it, keep them in a central place, and make it easy for other developers to understand and use. These databases are just not designed to perform in an "object" like manner (or at least perform well) yet.

Comment: Good, we think alike.  "Return objects" -- caution.  If an 'object' is always all the columns from a table, this could hurt if you decide later to split the table in two for performance reasons.  (OK, the main hurt is that you may need to change your API.)  "Trust ORMs" -- Often I encounter problems (esp. scaling) caused by inflexible 3rd party software.  More on pagination -- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination .  Object -- PHP associative arrays can help mask schema changes from the front end.

Comment: Yeah, I don't plan on returning all the columns of a table unnecessarily. But I guess you are right again, in that I should just stick to regular old arrays for R(Read) queries. For most CUD(Create,Update,Delete) stuff I can use repo classes, and these classes can call some of those Read queries, the simplest being a `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id=:id` in the form of `someTable->findById()` and know to accept an array to set into the repo object's own properties. So that I can turn around and do a `$repo->someField = $newValue; $repo->save()`.

Comment: After I'm done planning (hopefully in a few days), i'll post a clean code example of my solution here. I'd be interested to know what you think.

Comment: FYI, I personally don't like how ORM's always perform a sometimes unnecessary `->findById()` before you can ever do a `->save()`. I think I can come up some sort of `isDirty` function that will only save on those fields altered in an object (so that my INSERT/UPDATE query will only use those "dirtied" fields in the query).

Comment: <opinion>Blindly handling a row as a unit makes life easy for the ORM and any _toy_ applications built on it.  But it won't scale for serious applications.</opinion>